# Have 3d text shader be non-emissive?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity, how can I stop my 3d texts from "glowing" in the dark?

I'm using below shader code, for instance, but the texts turn up much brighter/ self-emissive than other things. Changing to "Lighting On" gets rid of the glow, but will then also get rid of the material color, and turn up black.

How to solve this? Many thanks!

```
Shader "GUI/3D Text Shader - Cull Back" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Font Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color ("Text Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}

SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    Lighting Off Cull Back ZWrite Off Fog { Mode Off }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Pass {
        Color [_Color]
        SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            combine primary, texture * primary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer exactly but you'll get more control if you design it as a fragment shader rather than use the built in directions https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html

Comment: Perhaps I've misread, but is it not possible to adjust the brightness of your `_Color` property from the material's inspector?

Comment: That will adjust the brightness of the RGB indeed, but it won't adjust the emissive brightness in the environment. Take for instance a text with the color rgb(255,0,0), which is a red; if absolutely no light sources are in my 3d scene, then this text would consequently not show (because it's pitch black). This works fine for any other 3d mesh, but fonts on the other hand will now be effectively "glow in the dark". (That glowing is reduced the less bright the color gets, but the problem still remains.)

Comment: I suspect the *emissive glow* is just the material's *unlit* color contrasting against a dark/variably lit scene? A lit shader could fix such an issue, however Unity's `TextMesh` component appears to not generate mesh normals and thus the shader's lighting calculations will corrupt (if at all be compiled). It explains why `Lighting On` outputs black. Without access to `TextMesh` internals and confined to the limitations of fixed-function shaders, a custom shader may be your only option here. I can post one to test, if you'd like?

Comment: Yes exactly, the "glow" will basically just be that color's perfect RGB displayed on screen as if it wasn't affected by the environment or 3d rendering, hence looking like its shiny. Yes, happy to test any shader you may have!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Copied from comments, added for context:*

I suspect the *emissive glow* is just the material's unlit color contrasting against a dark/variably lit scene? A lit shader could fix such an issue, however Unity's TextMesh component appears to not generate mesh normals and thus the shader's lighting calculations will corrupt (if at all be compiled). It explains why `Lighting On` outputs black. Without access to TextMesh internals and confined to the limitations of fixed-function shaders, a custom shader may be your only option.

The following is a basic Surface Shader using the Lambert lightning model. Under the hood it will compile to a standard vertex/fragment shader with Unity's lighting calculations *automagically* injected. It's been written as a drop-in replacement, so simply add it to your project and drag and drop it onto your material:

```
Shader "GUI/3D Text Shader - Lit"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Text Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Font Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
        Cull Back

        CGPROGRAM   
        #pragma surface SS_Main Lambert vertex:VS_Main alpha:blend 
        #pragma target 3.0

        uniform fixed4 _Color;
        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Output
        {
             float4 vertex    : POSITION;
             float3 normal    : NORMAL;     
             float4 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
             float4 texcoord1 : TEXCOORD1;
             float4 texcoord2 : TEXCOORD2;
        };

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };      

        void VS_Main (inout Output o) 
        {          
            // Generate normals for lighting.
            o.normal = float3(0, 0, -1);
        }

        void SS_Main (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {       
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Albedo = _Color.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Comment: All working now and marked as answer, thanks so much for your help! VR sandbox universe Anyland will appreciate it!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Excellent and you're welcome! Good luck with your project :)